# How to prevent MKMapView from loading content?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have an app where you can search for some places either using online api or by downloading the database with all data (name of the place, latitude, longitude, etc). If internet is present, i use online api and show the map. If there is no internet, i use database, but still show the map, because there is a chance that some portion of map is still cached. Now I'm trying to add a toggle to switch between online and offline mode, and I want to make sure that my app is not using any cell/wifi data while it is in offline mode.

I would like to be able to prevent the MKMapView in my app from loading the tiles from web, but show only cached content even when the internet connection is present. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?  If you dont want to show any content at all with no network connection, why even show the MKMapView period? Just show a completely different view in this case.

Comment: I have an app where you can search for some places either using online api or by downloading the database with all data (name of the place, latitude, longitude, etc). If internet is present, i use online api and show the map. If there is no internet, i use database, but still show the map, because there is a chance that some portion of map is still cached. Now I'm trying to add a toggle to switch between online and offline mode, and I want to make sure that my app is not using any cell/wifi data while it is in offline mode.

Comment: any update on this @almas ? How did you achieve offline mode of MKMapView when internet was available.

Comment: @SabirAli I didn't, there is no way to do that with MKMap as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this answer myself today and my best answer is that you will need to remove the MKMapView. Setting the view to hide it self(hidden =true) will not prevent downloading tiles.

```
[mapView removeFromSuperview];
```

Or just don't add it in the first place and add it when the user has internet.

Comment: It is obvious that you can remove the view to make it stop loading data, however, that doesn't answer my question =)